# php if statement based on previous click through url in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write an if statement based on the url of the previously click page_id

Something like this:

```
<?php 
$page_id = " the id or url of the page clicked to get to this page"
if($page_id){
    jr_register_form_jseeker( $redirect, $role ); 
}else{
    jr_register_form( $redirect, $role ); 
}
?>
```

I've looked at `is_page()` but that only seems to deal with the current page...?

Any ideas..?

Thanks

Comment: @StasGrin doesn't return the url on first click through only if you click again...? source via var_dump()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_get_referer()`. Read more about in [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer).

Or just call to: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no wordpress function that returns the id of the previous page. However, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. It should contain the ID of the previous page as a parameter. In combination with `parse_url` and `parse_str` you should be able to get the ID:

```php
parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $output);
$id = $output['p'];
```

(Not tested)

Comment: You're right. Though it seems to be pretty much the same as HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: yes, they are pretty common, but not equal. see line 1256 in functions.php

Comment: The url looks like this page_id=4&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fplum-vet-recruit%2F%3Fpage_id%3D63  using wp_get_referer() any idea how i can parse this to capture page-id=63 ...? thanks

Comment: It should work if you just replace 'p' in my code with 'page_id'.